# How to update column in a database with a function in a view using Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, controller

I am currently working on a project where if a date is in the past. The user should get an email notifying them there current 'Contract' finished. Now I already build the function where if the date is in the past the users gets the email but the problem is each time the users reloads the page it sends the email again. Now I added a column in my table named `email_send` what a default value of 0 but it doesn't seem to update from 0 to 1 when the function sends the email?

This is my sslController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class sslController extends Controller
{
    function SSL(){
        $data = DB::table('SSL')->where('userID', Auth::id())
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'SSL.userID')->get();
        return view('SSL',['data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

Note that the join is so that the loged in user only sees his own data in the table

This is the sslModel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class sslModel extends Model
{
    protected $table='SSL';
    protected $fillable = [
         'email_send',
    ];
}
```

and this is part of my ssl.blade.php:

```
</tr>
    @foreach ($data as $i )
       <tr>
         <td>
           {{$i->AanvraagID}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->Status}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->StartDatum}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->EindDatum}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->Leverancier}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->Product}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->Validatie}}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{$i->TypeCertificaat}}
         </td>
         <td class="wrong">
             @php  
                $date = new DateTime($i->EindDatum);
                $now = new DateTime();

                if($date < $now)  echo  'Certificaat verlopen';

                if ($date < $now && $i->email_send == 0) {
                $user = App\User::find(1)->first();
                $user->notify(new App\Notifications\TaksComplete);
                $user->update(['email_send' => 1]);
                }
              @endphp
           </td>
     </tr>
```

I also tried this:

```
if ($date < $now && $i->email_send == 0) {       

$user=App\User::find(1);
$user->notify(new App\Notifications\TaksComplete);                                                            $SSL=App\sslModel::find(1);
$SSL->email_send=1;
$SSL->update();
}
```

Comment: I think you better would do your logic in your controller and return the result to the view.

Comment: Any idea how I would implement this logic in my controller?

Comment: The update should be triggered when the view is displayed?

Comment: Yes.. unless the date is not in the past yet.

Comment: So you may move your logic from the view to your `sslController`

Comment: Also I recommend you to use Eloquent ORM to query your database see [https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#introduction)

Comment: Can you please show me how? I have been trying for a few hours now..

Comment: My sslController doesnt know stuff like DateTime()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208033/discussion-between-above-the-law-and-loic-lopez).

Answer (score 3):

if you are using find() function then don't use first()

```
$user=App\User::find(1);
$user->email_send=1;
$user->update();
```

if App\User is not working 
then
use App\Models\User;

```
$user=User::find(1);
$user->email_send=1;
$user->update();
```

For update sslModel

```
$sslModel=App\sslModel::where('userID', Auth::id())->first();
$sslModel->email_send=1;
$sslModel->update();
```

Comment: This does not work it tries to update my email_send in the users table wich is not there

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email_send' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `email_send` = 1, `users`.`updated_at` = 2020-02-18 08:11:42 where `id` = 1)

Comment: The problem is it tries to update in my users table but it should update in the SSL table!